# SQL - More efficient way instead of using a cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cursor

```
-- Declare the table we are interested in reverting.
DECLARE             @table_name                 VARCHAR(1000)
SET                 @table_name                 = 'tblCustomers'                                            -- change this

-- Declare cursor and use the select statement (the one we want to loop through).    
DECLARE             customer_cursor             CURSOR FOR
SELECT              C.CustomerId
FROM                tblCustomers                C
WHERE               ModifiedBy                  like '%crm%'
ORDER BY            C.CustomerId                DESC              

-- Open the cursor and copy the columns into the original_consumer variable.

DECLARE             @customer_id                INT

OPEN                customer_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM     customer_cursor               
INTO                @customer_id   

-- Now loop through the old consumer id's and update their corresponding purchase and refunds records.
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS ( SELECT TOP 1 UserName 
                FROM tblAudit
                WHERE TableName = @table_name
                AND TableId IN (
                                    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, CustomerId) 
                                    FROM tblCustomers                                                           -- change this
                                    WHERE CustomerId = @customer_id
                                )
                AND UserName != 'crmuser'
                ORDER BY TransactionDate DESC)
    BEGIN

        UPDATE          tblCustomers
        SET             ModifiedBy                  = (SELECT TOP 1 UserName 
                                                    FROM tblAudit
                                                    WHERE TableName = @table_name
                                                    AND TableId IN (
                                                                        SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, CustomerId) 
                                                                        FROM tblCustomers                       -- change this
                                                                        WHERE CustomerId = @customer_id
                                                                    )
                                                    AND UserName != 'crmuser'
                                                    ORDER BY TransactionDate DESC),

                        ModifiedDate                = (SELECT TOP 1 TransactionDate 
                                                    FROM tblAudit
                                                    WHERE TableName = @table_name
                                                    AND TableId IN (
                                                                        SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, CustomerId) 
                                                                        FROM tblCustomers                       -- change this
                                                                        WHERE CustomerId = @customer_id
                                                                    )
                                                    AND UserName != 'crmuser'
                                                    ORDER BY TransactionDate DESC)

        WHERE           CustomerId                  = @customer_id

    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM   customer_cursor           INTO @customer_id

END

-- Finally close and deallocate the cursor to stop memory leakage.
CLOSE customer_cursor
DEALLOCATE customer_cursor
```

Comment: This is a "convert my code task", not a focused problem. Explain what the goal is (e.g. what the behavior of the operation is), what the input is (e.g. scheme/multiplicities), and what relational algebra approach has already been tried and what difficulty (e.g. incorrect results/behavior) there is with it.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it might work:

```
UPDATE tblCustomers
SET ModifiedBy = a.UserName,
    ModofiedDate = amax.LatestChangeDate
from tblCustomers t
inner join -- get the latest transaction_date for each customer
(
    select customerId, max(transaction_date) LatestChangeDate
    from tblAudit
    where TableName = @table_name
) amax on amax.customerId = t.customer_id
inner join -- get the details of changes for customer and latest date
(
    select CustomerId, UserName, transaction_date
    from tblAudit
    where table_name = @table_name
) a on a.customerId = t.customerId and a.transaction_date = amax.LatestChangeDate
WHERE t.CustomerId = @customer_id
);
```

(I might have some of the column names wrong.)

Comment: Simon, this doesn't seem to work, also it still requires the cursor. Ideally I am trying to remove the cursor fully.

Answer (score 0):

BEGIN TRAN

SELECT            COUNT(*)
FROM        tblInvoices
WHERE       ModifiedBy = 'DataImporterUser'
;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT   TableId,
                  TransactionDate,
                  UserName,
                  TransactionDetail,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TableId ORDER BY TransactionDate DESC) AS rn
   FROM           tblAudit
   WHERE    TableName = 'tblInvoices'
   AND            UserName <> 'DataImporterUser'
)

UPDATE            C

SET               C.ModifiedBy      =     cte.UserName,
                  C.ModifiedDate    =     cte.TransactionDate

FROM        tblInvoices AS    C

INNER JOIN  cte
ON                cte.TableId       =     C.InvoiceId

WHERE       rn = 1

SELECT            COUNT(*)
FROM        tblEvents
WHERE       ModifiedBy        = 'DataImporterUser'

ROLLBACK